# Show that the limit of the following integral is the $L^2$-norm square

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\epsilon>0$, $f\in L^1(R)\cap L^2(R)$ and define

$$g_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/(2\varepsilon^2)}.$$

Show that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\overline{f(x+t)}g_\varepsilon(t) dt dx = \Vert f\Vert^2_{L^2}.$$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\overline{f(x+t)}g_\varepsilon(t) dt dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\overline{f(x+t)}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}g_\varepsilon(t) dt dx
\end{align*}

and

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} g_\varepsilon(t) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/(2\varepsilon^2)} = 0,$$

which means the integral is $0$. How does one resolve this?

Comment: Why can you swap the order of integration and the limit $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}$ in the third equation?

Comment: because $f$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$? I'm not sure

Comment: Is this related to this post by any chance? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718664/1104384

Comment: I think using the relation from the post I linked should make the $\|f\|^2_{L^2}$ appear naturally: you'd "only" have to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g_\varepsilon}(\xi)\vert \hat{f}(\xi)\vert^2 d\xi$ converges to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert \hat{f}(\xi)\vert^2 d\xi$ when $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I saw that post too but i wasn't able to pick up much from it unfortunately

Comment: In fact $g_\varepsilon(t)$ 'converges' (in a sense to be specified) to the Dirac delta $\delta(t)$ as $\varepsilon$ vanishes. This is the main intuition but there are a few steps to justify formally.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your attempt is that you can not swap the limit and the integration in the third line.

I will present a sketch of the proof.
We have that
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} f(x+t) g_\varepsilon (t) dt = \int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g_\varepsilon (t-x) dt = \int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g_\varepsilon (x-t) dt =f * g_\varepsilon (x).  $$
Where $f*g_\varepsilon$ is the convolution. We also have $f*g_\varepsilon \in L^2$.
Then the identity we want to prove reduces (with the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ anti-linear in the first component) to showing
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0 }\langle f * g_\varepsilon, f\rangle = \| f \|^2.$$
Now since the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ is unitary we have
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0 }\langle f * g_\varepsilon, f\rangle =\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0 }\langle \mathcal{F} (f * g_\varepsilon),\mathcal{F} f\rangle .$$
From the convolution theorem (using the fact that $f \in L^1 \cap L^2)$ we have
$$
\mathcal{F} (f * g_\varepsilon) = (2\pi)^{1/2} \mathcal{F} (f) \mathcal{F}(g_\varepsilon).
$$
We can compute $\mathcal{F}(g_\varepsilon)$ and show that it converges pointwise from below to $1/(2\pi)^{1/2}$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.
Applying dominated convergence with $4 |\mathcal{F}(f)|^2 $ as the dominator shows that $\mathcal{F}(f * g_\varepsilon) \to \mathcal{F}(f)$ in $L^2$.
Continuity of the map $\langle \cdot,\mathcal{F} f \rangle$ concludes the proof.

Comment: $\int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g_\varepsilon (t-x) dt = f * g_\varepsilon (x)$ is not quite true, as the convolution would be $\int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g_\varepsilon (x - t) dt = f * g_\varepsilon (x)$ instead. But seeing that $g_\varepsilon$ is even and thus $g_\varepsilon (t-x)$ is equal to $g_\varepsilon (x - t)$, it did not end up mattering (and it wouldn't have mattered *that* much).

Comment: @BrunoB well it is true since as you say $g_\varepsilon$ is even. But i agree i should add the extra step to my answer to avoid confusion.